# Detail in the shifted QR iteration algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

In one explanation of the shifted QR iteration algorithm I've read ([p. 537 of "Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra"](http://books.google.com/books?HL=EN&id=-7JeAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA537)), the following proposition is given (without proof):

At each step of the algorithm we have $\textbf Q^T=\textbf R(\textbf H-\alpha \textbf I)^{-1}$, and if $\alpha$ is close to some eigenvalue $\lambda$ then the rows of $\textbf Q^T$ are close to being left-hand eigenvectors of $\textbf H$ associated with the same $\lambda$.

[image: The explanation]

So my question is why are the rows of $\textbf Q^T$ close to being left-hand eigenvectors of $\textbf H$ associated with $\lambda$?

Comment: "one explanation of the shifted QR iteration algorithm I've read" - can you link to this, please?

Comment: Please add a Google Books link yourself the next time, whenever possible.